# DynaLoader.pm can't find libssl

Tags: macos, perl, openssl

I built a Perl library to deploy on with some CGI scripts on a web server using ExtUtils::MakeMaker (perl Makefile.PL, etc.). When I run "PERL5LIB=$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 make test" it builds like a champ and all tests pass.

However, when I try to deploy it to another project in which I installed all Perl dependencies into ./local/lib/perl5 (using carton), then attempt to install my custom lib

```
PER5LIB=local/bin/perl5 cpanm -L ./local .../MY-Lib.tar.gz
```

the tests fail because DynaLoader.pm cannot find libssl.1.0.0.dylib.

I already have libssl.1.0.0.dylib installed as /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib.

I even tried hacking the local Makefile in the cpan work directory and append "-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" to LDDLFLAGS and try re-running make test, but DynaLoader.pm still can't find libssl.

The first error message in the log is:

```
install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't load '$HOME/my-project/scripts/local/lib/perl5/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle' for module DBD::mysql: dlopen($HOME/my-project/scripts/local/lib/perl5/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle, 2): Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: $HOME/my-project/scripts/local/lib/perl5/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle
  Reason: image not found at /usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.0/lib/perl5/5.28.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DynaLoader.pm line 197.
```

How can I get DynaLoader.pm to find libssl when PERL5LIB is pointing to a local dir even with all prerequisites installed?  How can I debug this?

Comment: Does your linker know to look in that directory for libraries?  Not sure about the specifics of OS X, but there's probably a config file and/or environment variable that holds the list of directories to search.

Comment: The error is coming from the `dlopen` system call. Consult its man page?

Comment: @Shawn Thanks, I already tried with and without LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.  No luck.

Comment: @ikegami, thanki you. I noticed that the argument to dlopen() starts with '$HOME/...' which looks like $HOME hasn't been expanded to '/Users/...'. If I search my local env vars for HOME with "env | grep HOME" all I get is "HOME=/Users/..." which is what I'd expect.  So '$HOME' must be single-quoted somewhere in cpanm. This is way out of scope for my project, but I'll have to check.  Good catch!

Comment: oh yeah, duh! awesome

Comment: @ikegami - I think that was me that replaced the path to my home dir with $HOME in the post so as not to give away sensitive info.  I still have the problem.  I could create a soft link to /usr/local/opt/lib but I saw a warning about that weakening security so I'm reluctant.